# SDK2: scope and permissions for updateSettingsValues()

Tags: javascript, extjs4, rally

What is the scope of settings and updateSettingsValues(), and who can change them?  Are these settings scoped to that particular app, or are they scoped to each individual user of that particular app?

Also, who has permissions to change settings?  If you call updateSettingsValues() and the user is not at least a workspace admin, does it save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently settings are scoped to that particular app.  If it is on a shared custom page then those would apply to all users accessing it in the workspace.  In the near future we will add support for scoping them to a project (and possibly user).  If it is a shared page only workspace admins and above would be able to change the settings.  Otherwise any user should be able to (as long as they are not read-only).